# Negative lookbehind, allow other words in between

Tags: regex

The following would return NULL for `'im a cute hippo. you are a giraffe'` but how do I get the negative look behind to allow words in between cute and hippo? I tried `(?<!\scute.*)` but that's invalid and `(?<!\scute)[^.]*` allows everything with hippo.

`REGEXP_EXTRACT('im a cute and ugly hippo. you are a giraffe', '[^.?!]*(?<!\scute)hippo[^.?!]*[?.]')`

Want: return NULL

Answer (score 0):

Not all regex engines allow variable-length look-behinds. Yours appears to be one of those that don't. (You didn't say what exactly you're using, so I can't tell for sure.)

You can make due without look-behinds. This expression matches all sentences<sup>(*)</sup> where the word "cute" comes before the word "hippo".

```
[^.?!]*\bcute\b[^.?!]*\b(hippo)\b[^.?!]*[.?!]
```

You might need a second step to extract a substring from it, or maybe you can use the group.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> *"Sections of text delimited by `.`, `?`, or `!`."* This fails for all kinds of common scenarios, like quoted speech, or sentences with abbreviations or dates in them, etc, etc.

Comment: To clarify, I would like "i'm a cute and ugly hippo. you are a giraffe" to return NULL but currently it would only return NULL for "i'm a cute hippo. you are a giraffe". I tried the regex you suggested but it return "I'm a cute hippo". I'll try a second extraction step, thanks!

Comment: @jyu429 It might seem clear to you what you want, it's not clear to me. Try to describe the requirement differently.

Comment: Sure, I want to identify all sentences with the word 'hippo' in it but NOT if it has 'cute' anywhere in front of it. Did that help?

Comment: @jyu429 Ah of course. I would use two steps for that - identify all sentences with "hippo" with one expression, then use `AND NOT` to remove the ones you don't want to have. As a performance tweak, put the expression first that removes more rows from the result set, depending on your data.